# HTML+CSS: Horizontal sub menu, always showing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am learning HTML+CSS to create a simple website, with a menu at the top. When the mouse cursor hovers over one of the menu items, it expands and shows a submenu.

The submenu is another horizontal menu bar, unlike the usual vertical submenu items we usually see in application. I hope I have helped you visualize it.

Now, the submenu is working properly, but it shows up only when the mouse cursor hovers. I want the submenu to show always. Is it possible in HTML + CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: show us some code (and image reference, if possible)

Comment: Please provide your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to use simple jQuery there. 
Simple Click function can do all you want.
add this in the bottom of your code, just after closing body tag.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('your Menu Div Selector').click(function(){
        $('you dropdown div selector').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

something like this